# dividing up a cube into uneven 27 seperate cubes

Tags: modeling

I am going to model a mirror cube

[image]

I used a loop cut to place the lines where they need to be for each piece, but I'm not sure how to get the loop cut to also cut a line through the inside so when I go into edit mode I could select the faces for each piece of the cube and separate by selection. I tried selecting each edge and click F, but that didn't put vertices where the edges intersected, so I couldn't properly do what I thought I could do. Maybe there is a way I'm not thinking about. I remembered to attach the blend file below this time.

[image]

[image]

I finished it by doing what Carlo suggested. Here is the result

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that’s not going to work. What you need is bisect.

Comment: It's probably easier to model the cubes with a triple array modifier and then tweak the proportions.

Comment: Could use booleans

Comment: @Carlo I just added all the cubes I needed over the previous cube and went to edit mode for each cube and moved the faces to snap to the lines I cut in the first cube. I posted the resulting image above

Comment: Great! I'm glad the comment was useful and you succeed. The final result looks very nice.